# How many of each fish does Traders and Barbarians have?

Tags: catan-traders-and-barbarians

How many 1, 2, and 3 fish tiles are in the Traders and Barbarians expansion and Traders and Barbarians 5-6 Player extension? The most I've garnered from various web sites is that there are 20 fish tiles total in the base expansion and 14 more fish tiles in the extension, but I would like a breakdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>According to the [World of Catan Wiki](http://catan.wikia.com/wiki/Fishermen_of_Catan):</strike>

Edit: According to [this base game photo](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/359014/catan-traders-barbarians) and [this expansion photo](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/750616/catan-traders-barbarians-5-6-player-extension)  from BoardGameGeek:

Base game (Total 30 tokens):

```
29 Fish tokens:
  11 1-Fish
  10 2-Fish
  8 3-Fish 
1 "Old Shoe" token
```

Expansion (Total 14 tokens):

```
14 Fish tokens:
  4 1-Fish
  5 2-Fish
  5 3-Fish
```